# Which method of finding object is better findByClient vs findByClientId?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my client app in JPA repositories there are JpaRepository queries like findByClient which take as a argument Client object and findByClientId which take as a argument client id. And I want to refactor it all to findById. Which method of finding client object is actually better, faster and why?

Answer (score 0):

They will do the same.

So even if you pass the Client as argument only the clientId will be compared.

You can check it out by turning on the SQL logging of Hibernate.